# Proof this trigonometry sin a +sin b =c and cos a + cos b=c where c≠ 0 show sin b +cos b=c

Tags: trigonometry

If Sin a + sin b=c and cos a + cos b=c show that sin b + cos b=c where  c≠0
 Can anyone give me a clue how to start??

Answer (score 2):

The question is wrong and I bring you a counter example:

$$\sin 0 + \sin \pi =0$$

$$\cos 0 + \cos \pi =0$$

But

$$\sin \pi + \cos \pi =-1$$

Comment: But what if c≠0 any idea??

Answer (score 0):

If $c\ne0,\cos\dfrac{a-b}2\ne0$

using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas,

$$\tan\dfrac{a+b}2=1\implies\dfrac{a+b}2=n\pi+\dfrac\pi4\iff a+b=2n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies\sin a=\cdots=\cos b$ and $\cos a=\cdots=\sin b$

Comment: Can you elaborate more?? Thank

Comment: @Ameet,  Apply Prosthaphaeresis Formula on $\sin a+\sin b,\cos a+\cos b$  and divide

Comment: After getting a+b =2pi +pi/2 what should i do??

Comment: @Ameet,, $a=2n\pi+\dfrac\pi2-b\implies\sin a=?$

Comment: I get the answer but how i  can  relate it to the question?? Sorry im quite weak in this chapter

Comment: I get the answer  but how i can relate it to the question (sin b+cos b=c) sorry im quite weak in this chapter